# Does NodeJS crypto module fail verification if the RSA cert is expired?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

If 'key' in the following code is an expired cert, will res always be false regardless of the signature's validity?

```
var verifier = crypto.createVerify("RSA-SHA1")
verifier.update(str)
var res = verifier.verify(key, signatureValue, 'base64')
```

In other words, does the NodeJS crypto module care about a certificate's expiration when validating a signature. This is all in the context of validating a signed XML document.

Answer (score 1):

No, the expiration is not validated using the code above. If you directly use the public key instead of the signature then the algorithm doesn't even receive the end-of-validity date.

If the `key` in your code is not a key but a certificate then the signature verification does normally not fail either. The test to see if the certificate is valid should be performed *before* the signature over the data is verified.

The **certificate verification and validation procedures** in other words should contain the check that the certificate is in its validity period - among all the other checks. Signature verification should only take place after that.

Comment: The expiration date is embedded in the certificate value, is it not? My question is if verifier.verify cares about that date or not.

Comment: @cava23 No, it doesn't.  It only checks that the signature is correct, _you_ need to check that the current date falls within the keys valid usage period.